# drive_service.files().list throws TimeoutException error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am writing the below in a Lambda function to get the files from a Google Drive folder ID but I get `TimeoutException` error most of the time.

Sometimes the Lambda function is working and I get the files but in most triggers it **times out**. What could be possible causes?

```py
    query = f"'{folder_id}' in parents"
    print(query)
    retry_count = 0
    while retry_count < max_retries:
        try:
            # set a timeout for the API call
            signal.alarm(timeout)
            files_test = drive_service.files().list().execute()
            files = drive_service.files().list(q=query, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
            # disable the timeout if the call was successful
            signal.alarm(0)
            print(files)
            return files
        except HttpError as error:
            # print detailed error message
            print(f"An error occurred: {error}. Details: {error.content}")
        except TimeoutException:
            print("The API call timed out.")
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the Lambda function ends due to a Timeout? Have you tried increasing the Timeout setting?

Comment: No @JohnRotenstein the lambda doesn't Timeout. I edited the code with the whole function. The API call times out. The code goes to the except TimeoutException: part. Then it retries but it doesn't succeed.

Comment: Is the Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, is there a reason why you have done this? To access Google Drive, the Lambda function requires Internet access. This is either available by _NOT_ connecting the Lambda function to a VPC, or by placing the Lambda function in private subnets of a VPC with a NAT Gateway in a public subnet.